# non-numeric argument to binary operator is the error i am getting

Tags: r, data-science, static-analysis

```
list =ls()
set.seed(1234)
S<- numeric()
Y_bar <- numeric()
Xsq <- numeric()
T_st <- numeric()

for (i in c(1:10000)) {
  sample = rnorm(n= 20, mean=2, sd = 5) 
  s = var(sample)
  S <-append(S,s)
  
  y_bar = mean(sample)
  Y_bar<-append(Y_bar,y_bar)
  
  xsq = n-1*s**2/5**2
  Xsq <-append(Xsq,xsq)
  
  t_st = y_bar - mean/( as.numeric(s)/sqrt(n))
  T_st <-append(T_st,t_st)
  
}
```

> Error in mean/(as.numeric(s)/sqrt(n)) :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator

> Error in sd^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I need all these calculated values like `s` and `y_bar` for my later calculations.

Comment: Hello, revise your code, you don't have any variable with name sd

Comment: Try adding: n=20, mean=2, sd=5 outside of the for loop.

Comment: i do have sd =5?

Comment: If you type print(sample) inside the for loop, you'll see that you don't those variables defined at all.

Comment: but i do need 10000 observations of normal and with each sample need to record values

Comment: Won't they all have the same sd, mean, and n?

Comment: samples <- replicate(10000, rnorm(20, mean = 2, sd = 5)) like this?

Comment: i am still getting the same errors

Comment: So, I don't think you need to use replicate(). You issue is that you did not have sd, mean, or n defined. You haven't defined them anywhere. You used them as arguments in rnorm(), but they aren't stored anywhere in your variable 'sample'. It's just a list of values. So, somewhere else (probably OUTSIDE the for loop), you could define sd=5, mean=2, n=20. That way, when you call those variables inside the for loop, there are values associated with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sense is there is some confusion. You are specifying the mean, `mean` and sample size `n` as parameters in the in the `rnorm` function but not assigning them as objects in the global environment. They are not saved (as they would be with `mean <- 5`).

Sticking to your original code as much as possible (though this could be optimized), a more proper way to run this loop is to define your sample size, mean, and standard deviation, in the global environment and use that to specify the parameters (then replace accordingly throughout).

```
set.seed(1234)
S <- numeric()
Y_bar <- numeric()
Xsq <- numeric()
T_st <- numeric()

# specify sample size, mean, and sd
sample_n <- 20
sample_mn <- 2
sample_sd <- 5

for (i in c(1:10000)) {
  # specify parameters from those defined in the global environment
  sample = rnorm(n = sample_n, mean = sample_mn, sd = sample_sd)
  s = var(sample)
  S <- append(S, s)
  
  y_bar = mean(sample)
  Y_bar <- append(Y_bar, y_bar)
  
  # Change object names accordingly
  xsq = sample_n - 1 * s ** 2 / 5 ** 2
  Xsq <- append(Xsq, xsq)
  
  t_st = y_bar - sample_mn / (as.numeric(s) / sqrt(sample_n))
  T_st <- append(T_st, t_st)
}
```

Note that I used terms like `sample_mn` since `mean <- 5` is not good practice since `mean()` is already a function.